# Interactive console in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, console, interactive

I've seen a few posts about this, but very few that provide an accurate answer.

In short, my brothers is just learning the smaller subtleties of Java, and I recommended him start off with Eclipse as, though a little intimidating at first, I find that it is the most flexible tool.

The problem is, that his professor (who said he may use any editor he wanted, FYI), told him to do some simple math by typing it into the console window.

The problem, is of course that the console isn't interactive in Eclipse.

Is there any plugin or magic that can enable such an interactive console for him? Personally, I've never needed it, but he's in a situation where he does, and I told him I'd consult the experts.

**NOTE:** Forgive the slightly technical question. I will gladly take it elsewhere if this is not the place to ask, but I couldn't think of any place better for a question about Eclipse.

Comment: I'm missing something here. If you have a java class with a `public static void main(String[] args) { ...}` method you should just be able to run it as a Java Application. You can get input from the console using a `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an Eclipse scrapbook page:

Create using "File / New / Other / Java / Java Run/Debug / Scrapbook Page"

Then write some code, select it and right-click Execute to run it.

This is not as interactive as javarepl, but it is native to Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of this functionality within Eclipse , but I believe this satisfies your need :
    http://www.javarepl.com/console.html

Comment: That being said , it's possible your brothers' professor intends him to write a simple program that enables him to type into the console . If this is the case I would advise to look at this : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html

Comment: I wanted to give you my thanks, despite not being exactly what I was looking for, I never knew such a utility existed. So here's a bump and a thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a "terminal" window to open jshell.

once created the terminal window can be opened from window - show view - terminal.

[image: Create terminal]

[image: Terminal running]